# Converging sequences, with converging partial sums, and converging partial sums of partial sums, and so on

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\mathcal S$ be the operator, which takes a sequence $\boldsymbol{a}=\{a_n\}$ to the sequence of partial sums of $\boldsymbol{a}$, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal S\boldsymbol a=\boldsymbol b=\{b_n\}, \qquad \text{where $\,\,b_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$}.
$$

**Question.** *Is there any non-zero sequence $\boldsymbol{a}=\{a_n\}$, such that all the sequences $\boldsymbol{a}, \mathcal S\boldsymbol a, \mathcal S^2\boldsymbol a,\ldots,\mathcal S^k\boldsymbol a,\ldots,$ converge*?

Clearly, if such a sequence exists, then its limit should be equal to zero, and so should be the limits of all the sequences $\mathcal S^k\boldsymbol a$, $k\in\mathbb N$.

Note that, $\mathcal S\boldsymbol a=a_1,/,a_1+a_2,\,a_1+a_2+a_3,\ldots,$ 
$\mathcal S^2\boldsymbol a=a_1,\,2a_1+a_2,\,3a_1+2a_2+a_3,\ldots,$ etc.

Comment: Just to be clear, $S^2 a = S(Sa) = S(a_1+a_2+\dots) = (a_1+a_2+\dots) + (a_1+a_2+\dots) + \dots $ ?

Comment: I clarified the meaning of $\mathcal S^k\boldsymbol a$ in my revised question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got an answer, and it is positive.

Let $\{a_n\}$ such a sequence. It is convenient in my argument to start from $n=0$.

Set $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Since $\{a_n\}$ converges, and since $a_n\to 0$, then $f$ is analytic in the unit disc and further, the limit $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)$ exists ($x$ real) and it is equal to zero. The analytic function which corresponds to $\mathcal S\boldsymbol a$ is clearly
$$
g(z)=(1+z+z^2+\cdots )f(z)=\frac{f(z)}{1-z},
$$
and clearly, $g(1)=0$. Repeating the argument, we obtain that $f$ has a root of infinite order at $z=1$, which of course is impossible, unless $1$ is an essential singularity.

Indeed,
$$
f(z)=\mathrm{e}^{-1/(z-1)^2},
$$
has the desired properties!

So, if  $\mathrm{e}^{-1/(z-1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, then $\{a_n\}$ converges together with all its the partial sums and the partial sums of its partial sums, etc.